# Steps for Developing FCAPS based Network Monitoring system

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, networking, snmp, network-monitoring

I am new in development world and curious to know the steps to be followed for developing a SNMP based **Network or Element Monitoring System(NMS)**  for  element like **wifi AP's** (FCAPS(fault, configuration, accounting, performance, security) model).
Below are the feature I need to accommodate:

1. A WebBased GUI to discover wifi AP over SNMPv2 or v3.
2. Monitor wifi-AP RF and other performances using wifi-AP **REST API**.
3. Saving elements statistics and other information into the database.
4. Alarm and Event monitoring
5. Presenting realtime performance graph over NMS webUI.
6. Configuration of device parameters.

This is the idea which I want to learn to develop, and I am having experience of **Python and JS**.
Need support on how I can proceed further for developing such web base monitoring system using Python as I have experience on it.

Appreciate your help and support towards devloping a FCAPS based network monitoring system.